# WSO2 ESB blocking address by proxy

Tags: security, proxy, wso2, firewall, wso2-esb

In my usecase i have a black-list, stored inside the WSO2 ESB registry, containing a list of forbidden REST URL paths (i.e. /myservice/myethod1; /myservice/myethod2; /myservice/myethod3;).

I need to have a proxy able to block all the incoming requests having an url containing one of the black paths listed.
For example, proxy must to block an http request having this url:

```
http://localhost:8280/myapplication/REST/myservice/mymethod1/param1/param2
```

What's the best way to do it?

Does WSO2 ESB  have a security policy which already do this?

or

Can i do this simply using the proxy configuration?

or

is writing my own custom mediator the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Filter Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator) or [Conditional Router Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Conditional+Router+Mediator) if you can manually specify the blacklisted urls in the proxy.

If you need to read the urls from a file, I think it's best to go for a custom Class mediator.